# How the byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays

Tags: java, byte

> The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has
>   a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive). The
>   byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays, where
>   the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in place of
>   int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact that a
>   variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation.

I see this in java documentation.My question is how the byte data type will save the memory in large arrays?.I confused with this

Thanks in advance....

Comment: In fact, when you load a file into memory, it is common to use an array of bytes. It is the most optimal way of doing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What it is saying is really very simple.

Suppose I have 40 "numbers" to store.  If I store them in the following:

```
    byte[] numbers = new byte[40];
```

it will take less space than if I store them in the following:

```
    int[] numbers = new int[40];
```

Why?  Because in an array, 40 `byte` instances occupies 40 bytes of memory, but 40 `int` instances occupies 40 x 4 = 160 bytes of memory.

---

Caveats:

1. Obviously, this only works if the numbers are small enough to be represented as `byte` ... without overflow; i.e. they must be in the range -128 to +127
2. This does NOT apply to simple variables.  In Java a `byte` variable and an `int` variable typically occupy 4 bytes each.  (It is a low-level JVM thing which would take a lot of explaining ...)
3. I'm glossing over the fact that heap memory *may* be allocated at a granularity that is coarser than 4 bytes.  The allocation granularity is typically 8 bytes.  However, for **large** arrays, the contribution of the allocation granularity is negligible.  Likewise, I am glossing over the contribution of array headers for the above reason, AND because the contribution header is the same irrespective of the array's base type.

Answer (score 1):

For instance you have an array of 1000000 integers. If you use int[] it will take up 4Mb of memory. But if you know that all values are within the range of -128 to 127 you can use byte[] and it will take up 4 times less memory